# Are you able to check where you are scrolled to with <a name=#page> in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, scroll

I'm trying to code a site to host a comic, and each page is reached by scrolling with < a name=#page(number) > in html. 
So the button to go to the next page would be:

```
<a href = #page1></a>
```

Then, later in the code would be:

```
<a name = #page1></a>
```

Which would make the button scroll to there. 
But I'd also like to implement being able to use arrow keys, which would require knowing what #page you are on, and use it to set a variable as the next page number, to use on my arrow key checker, which is now in a javascript file:

```
case 39:
window.location = "willow.html#page" + nextPage;  
break;
```

I've tried

```
if (location.href === "example.com/index.html#page1") {
    var nextPage = 2;
}
```

And it doesn't work. Is there some way to check what < a name > you are at in javascript?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

You can use `location.hash` to check which `"#anchor"` (which may be a `name=` or an `id=`) was used. It won't reflect scrolling, but will reflect the address bar and any in-page links you click.

```
if (location.hash === "#page1") {
    var nextPage = 2;
}
```